# Print a Component react in the ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, printing

Iḿ trying to print a component after render, but the "document.getElementById" is telling me THE NEXT ERROR:
[image]

hERE IS MY CODE:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "../../styles/module/ticket.css";
import { clearSale } from "../../actions/Operations";
import { UNKNOWN_EMPLOYEE } from "constants/ActionTypes";

class AttrTicket extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const printableElements = document.getElementById("formToPrint").innerHTML;
    const orderHTML =
      "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +
      printableElements +
      "</body></html>";
    const oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = orderHTML;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
    localStorage["sale_employee"] = UNKNOWN_EMPLOYEE;
    this.props.clearSale();
    window.location.replace(""); 
  }

  render() {

      return (
        <div id="formToPrint" class="ticket">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <h1>Hola</h1>
          <h1>Bye</h1>
          <h1>Adios</h1>
          <h1>Smileee</h1>
      
        </div>
      );
    }
  
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, { clearSale })(AttrTicket);
```

I would appreciate a lot if you could help me

Comment: what are you trying to do really? Normally direct DOM manipulation in React is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Hello Prattek, I am new to React, sorry, I didn't know it was an anti-pattern, I try to print a ticket after a sale, so when the sale is done, I execute this component, after a status is modified in Redux, the Printing has to be automatic, and after printing, close the printing window. without having interaction with the user.

Comment: I'm doing a POS for a Store  with React.

Comment: Do post your whole component code?

Comment: I delete the data that is passed through "Props" and that is rendered in the component, but they are simple h1 tags for example. So I think it shouldn't influence when it goes to the Didupdate